# Why is firebase populating my viewholder with the same image from Firebase Storage

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage, android-recyclerview

I have a blog app that consists of username,profileImage,description and postImage. I am using this code to retrieve these items from firebase

```
 FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog,BlogViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder>(

            Blog.class,
            R.layout.blog_row,
            BlogViewHolder.class,
            mDatabase.orderByChild("TimeOrder")

    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final BlogViewHolder viewHolder, Blog model, int position) {


            viewHolder.setDescription(model.getDescription());
            if (isAdded()) {
                viewHolder.setImage(getActivity(), model.getPostimage());
            }
            viewHolder.setUid(model.getUid());//get username and profile picture from this
```

Everything is fine except that the about two postImages are repeated throughout the recyclerview. The profile picture also are from the same user ie One or two pictures are used as profile pictures of the rest of the users.
This is the code for **setImage**

```
 public void setImage(final Context con, final String image){

            final ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.post_image);


            if (postbool) {

                Picasso.with(con).load(image).placeholder(R.drawable.unnamed).error(R.drawable.imageerror).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE).into(imageView, new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {

                        postbool = false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {

                        Picasso.with(con).load(image).placeholder(R.drawable.unnamed).into(imageView);

                        postbool = false;
                    }
                });

            }
        }
```

This are a few screenshots. The profile picture is the same.
Where am I going wrong?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be due to cache issues! My suggestion, always **reset** all the views in the `ViewHolder` before populating values.

```
@Override
    protected void populateViewHolder(final BlogViewHolder viewHolder, Blog model, int position) {
        **reset all views**
        viewHolder.setDescription("");
        viewHolder.imageview.setImageDrawable(null);
        viewHolder.setUid("");

        viewHolder.setDescription(model.getDescription());
        if (isAdded()) {
            viewHolder.setImage(getActivity(), model.getPostimage());
        }
        viewHolder.setUid(model.getUid());//get username and profile picture from this
```

Please let me know how it goes!